# How to read QR Code from image gallery in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, qr-code

My app has a qr code scanner functionality, I am using `react-native-qrcode-scanner` to scan qr code via the camera.

User can also choose the image which contain a qrcode from their phone gallery. The problem is when user choose a image that is containing a QR Code, I cannot read and extract the data from the qrcode in the image. I am using `react-native-image-crop-picker` to access the images in the gallery.